# Pass lists of columns to Pandas DataFrame instead of lists of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a DataFrame like this:

```
column_names= ["a", "b", "c"]
vals = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=column_names)
```

Which results in the following DataFrame:

```
  a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

I suppose this is the expected result. However, I am trying to achieve this result:

```
  a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Where each nested list in `vals` corresponds to a whole column instead of a row.

Is there a way to get the above DataFrame without changing the way the data is passed to the constructor? Or even a method I can call to transpose the DataFrame?

Comment: Do you want also change index and columns names? after transpose?

Comment: the output clearly shows that to be true. I dont think we need to close this question because problem is how to feed a row-wise list data of column-wise data to a pd.dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `zip` it:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(column_names, vals)))
```

Outputs:

```py
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`transpose(df.T)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
In [3397]: df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)

In [3398]: df.columns = column_names

In [3399]: df
Out[3399]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the column naming in a difference step -

```
column_names= ["a", "b", "c"]
vals = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(vals).T
df.columns = column_names
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

---

Or if you can use numpy, you can do it in one step -

```
import numpy as np

column_names= ["a", "b", "c"]
vals = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

df = pd.DataFrame(vals.T, columns=column_names)
print(df)
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

If use constructor simplier is use `zip` with unpacking list with `*`:

```
column_names= ["a", "b", "c"]
vals = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*vals), columns=column_names)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Solutions if already was created DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=column_names)
```

Use [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and reassign columns with index values:

```
df1 = df.T
df1.columns, df1.index = df1.index, df1.columns
print (df1)

   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

One line solution with transpose, [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.T.set_axis(column_names, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Or transpose only numpy array, thank you @Henry Yik:

```
 df.loc[:] = df.T.to_numpy()
```